# Overriding GetHashCode() - how important is random distribution of hashes?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

In anticipation of first comments, I do understand some hash table theory so please read on...

I have a mutable reference type (contents can change) that is used as key in a `Dictionary`.

Yes this is intentional (in fact unavoidable).  The `Dictionary` grows to millions of entries and I wish to optimise access by key.

My objects do have a guaranteed-unique, private, integer field which seems a potentially ideal hash code in that underlying hashtable collisions would be impossible, however these are (nearly) sequential 1,2,4,5,6,9,10,11,...

***In Principle*** : Should I do this

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return myUniqueId;
}
```

or this

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return GenerateRandomInt(seed:myUniqueId);
  // where a 1:1 relationship exists between input seeds and output pseudo random numbers
  // (still avoiding hash collisions but at the cost of the PRNG call)
}
```

*from a hashtable-theory / best-practice point-of-view*, or is the answer likely to be implementation-specific (I'd have to measure - probably per deployment environment)?

Eric Lippert mentions random distribution as a "guideline" in this blog article: [Lippert Fabulous adventures in coding](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode)

Comment: "*Yes this is intentional (in fact unavoidable)*" -- bear in mind the Dictionary caches hash codes, so if your key is mutated, Dictionary simply won't notice. But removing that item then becomes impossible

Comment: If you needed to "randomize" the values, I doubt the (up to 32-bit) integers would just return their own values directly.

Comment: @canton7 They specify that while the object is mutated, the identity for the purposes of equality isn't, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Try both and measure the performance of each.  Rather than asking strangers on the internet to guess whether or not this change has a significant impact on your program, *run it and find out* whether there's a material difference, and if so, which performs better for *your* data in *your* situation.

Comment: @Servy I addressed that too (in a roundabout way) - several deployment environments, 32, 64 bit, Microsoft and non-Microsoft.  It's why I'm interested in matters of principle.  Traditional hashtables use "buckets" and documentation often mentions a "random, uniformly distributed" (or similar wording) requirement for hash codes. I've added a link in my question to an Eric Lippert article which does so mention.

Comment: @AlanK That makes it even less likely that the decision will matter.  If you need to care about all of those contexts then you'd need to test on all of them, and determine if one option is enough better on enough contexts that you'd want to choose it over another.  That you're planning to rely on private implementation details of how the structure maps hashes to buckets is all the less likely to be productive when you care about lots of different environments.  But regardless, the best way to find out is to test, not to ask strangers on the internet.

Comment: @Servy your point is obviously well intended but in this instance I'd call it misguided.  I posted the question because SO is *the* place on the internet to ask "strangers on the internet" for insight.  If I'm left with no alternative to experimentation I'll do it and post the results here.

Comment: @AlanK No, SO is not what you do instead of testing your code to figure out if you have a performance problem.  No one here can answer that question with even a small level of confidence.  That's a *really* bad way of figuring out if you have a performance problem, and your answer is *way* less reliable than just running the code that you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near-sequential integers as the hashcode will distribute your keys nicely among the buckets of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`'s hash table.

Dictionary uses the [following formula](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs#L327) to decide which bucket an item will go into:

```
int targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;
```

So you will achieve near-perfect distribution with a near-sequential id leading to a minimal amount of collision-resolution when making lookups.

Just use your `uniqueId` value. Job done.

Comment: The insight I was looking for.  Obrigado.